# Calculate inbox based on dynamic groups

Tags: sql, hadoop, memcached, dynamic-data, infinispan

I am facing this problem when calculating the inbox for a user:

- On one hand I have a bunch of documents that can potentially have
  many readers (DOCS table).
- Each reader belongs to one or more defined groups of users.
- I have a table DOC_ACCES_BY_GROUP with (DOC_ID, GROUP_ID)
- I need to know if a user has read a document or not. So, I have a table DOC_UNREAD with (DOC_ID, USER_ID) so that if a document is in that table, the user has not read the document yet.

Then each group can change in participants at any time, so I need to calculate my "inbox" for a certain user in real time.

**The first guess is:** Calculate all the groups in which a user is involved, then make a join between all the DOCS and the DOC_ACCESS_BY_GROUP table to get all the documents for that user (with the data asociated), and then another join to see if that document is read or not for the user.

The problem is, when my DOCS table grows considerably and I have many users, and many groups... the performance is really poor.

I'm trying to abstract the problem, which is actually a bit more complex. The possibility of storing document permissions per user is discarded. I also imagine it's not a problem that can be solved by optimizing the SQL query but should be done by software. We also support many data bases such as Mysql, Posgre or MSSQL so it can not be linked to a specific vendor solution (I guess).

So, the question is: Does anyone know any mechanism or framework or algorithm to do things differently and solve this problem, **in an optimal and performant way**?

Memcached? Infinispan? Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to "materialize" the inbox and update it every time the user reads something, the membership of a group changes etc. The materialized inbox could be stored either in a DB table or in a separate system like Infinispan/memcached.